# ERROR: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, ubuntu-18.04, ora-12545

I followed this steps to install Oracle 19.6.0 for Ubuntu 18.04:

https://medium.com/@TechExpertise/installing-oracle-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-bfa4af959deb

Then for some reason I was not able to open sqlplus, so I followed this steps as solution:

https://gist.github.com/tcnksm/7316877

And now I want to log in sqlplus by typing `sqlplus / as sysdba`, but I am getting:

> ERROR: ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does
>   not exist

So I think I have to make the appropriate settings in listener.ora and tnsnames.ora,
but I am missing this files.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Oracle isn't certified nor supported on Ubuntu. Is there any particular reason you want to use this combination? If it has to be Linux, why wouldn't you use Red Hat or Oracle Linux, or even download virtual box machine with preinstalled Oracle software on Linux? Yes, you might make your combination of Oracle software and operating system work, but - why?

Comment: @Littlefoot I recently changed to Linux Ubuntu, because my CPU and Disk usage was very high with Windows and my PC was working slowly.

Comment: OK, I understand. It's just that Oracle database isn't happy with Ubuntu.

Comment: Even if you could get it installed and "working", as many claim to have done, Oracle doesn't certify its product on Ubuntu at all. There's no telling what could go wrong or not work properly behind the scenes, and you wouldn't be able to get any effective support for it. The only supported Linux variations for Oracle Database are Oracle Linux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, and SUSE Enterprise Linux.

Comment: @pmdba I have successfully installed SQL Developer 19 on Ubuntu, the problem is that I cannot log in sqlplus to create my own account and give it all privileges for creating a database connection

Comment: Is the database available as a network resource on some other host - i.e. not on Ubuntu? "conn / as sysdba" requires operating system authentication. It can't be done over a network connection, so I assumed you had that installed on Ubuntu as well. And just to be clear, SQL Developer doesn't actually include the database software or SQL Plus; it's just a another developer IDE/client and requires a separate database installation.

Comment: @pmdba No it is not available as another network resource. Yes, you are right. SQL Developer doesn't include SQL Plus, so i had to install it separately.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Developer and SQL*Plus are client only tools that connect to a database that must be running somewhere: either on the same host or on another host.

If this database exists you should have its [connect string](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpqr/index.html#SQPQR121) to connect to it with SQL Developer or SQL*Plus

If this database does not exist, you must first create it: there are several ways to do this in addition to install Oracle Database (server - not client) and to create a database:

1. install Oracle XE 18c on Oracle Linux or Windows: installation will install database software and create a database at the same time (easier for non database specialist)
2. use a pre-installed VM such as: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/databaseappdev-vm.html.